# OpenGL Rotate Box

Tags: java, opengl

I most likely have this wrong, but in my camera class, I rotate and translate the whole scene around the camera so it looks like the camera is actually moving.  This works fine since all of the boxes in my game are axis aligned. I now want to rotate one of the boxes, but glRotate isn't working since I am using in the camera to rotate the scene.  Does anyone know any ways to rotate the whole scene and then rotate a part individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are drawing the object you want to rotate you can do a push matrix, rotate, draw, and a pop matrix.

```
void display() { // display callback function
   glPushMatrix(); 
   glRotate(...); // rotation
   myObject.draw(); // draw the objects you want to rotate
   glPopMatrix();
}
```

Before you push matrix:

You may first need to change the matrix mode from projection to modelview or call glLoadIdentity();

Comment: Edited for clarity. You push and pop in your display callback function and draw the objects you want to rotate in between the two calls.

Comment: Hmm, I'm doing everything you saying, but it is still not rotating :/